# Need pvr.vbox KODI addon build instructions for Android and iOS

Tags: android, python, ios, xbmc, kodi

I'm very interested in KODI addon. Especially I want to know about the pvr.vbox kodi addon.

The following link is one for the VBox Home TV Gateway PVR Client
https://github.com/kodi-pvr/pvr.vbox.

But there are only build instructions for Windows/Linux. I think that KODI is a cross-platform project, so I believe there is Android/iOS addon for it.

Comment: Hey David, I'm not a KODI expert, but if you're looking for android/iOS build instructions, consider also posting an issue on their github.

Comment: I already post the issue for it. But they said that they have no idea how to build for either of those platforms, and closed my issue.

Comment: I guess that means those platforms are not supported then. Adding a new platform is usually not a trivial undertaking, so if the core project won't help you, it is not supported.